# Creating a bootable USB through android

Tags: stock-android, android-device-manager

Is there any way to create a bootable USB (not turn your android device into a bootable USB), with an OTG USB stick through android?

I do not have a laptop to do this on, as the one I need (the one i need to bootable USB for, and the one i need to fix)no longer has an OS installed nor a CD drive. So any help would be much appreciated.

I am aware of the app to turn your android device into a bootable USB, but that does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussions with OP, he has

- Broken Win 10 machine, unable to get into OS
- Rooted Android

He wants to

- Extract Data from the Win machine
- Install OS

**Solution**

- Install [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) ( requires *root* ) which can

> DriveDroid allows you to boot your PC from ISO/IMG files stored on your phone. This is ideal for trying Linux distributions or always having a rescue-system on the go... without the need to burn different CDs or USB pendrives

- From the developers [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2196707), download *Hiren's boot CD* (for windows) - link in OP into the Android device
- Enter BIOS of your machine and set the Boot order to boot from USB as first choice ( key combination would be based on the machine and Google can help)
- Connect Android to device and boot, device will recognised and a temporary Win environment Win XP / 7 can be created. Connect an external drive and transfer files to drive

**Above based on my personal experience in getting data out of  dead Win XP**

**Installing new OS**

- In my case, CD was working so I installed OS again
- One of the reviews ( by Steffen Mossefin) claims he was able to do that using this app.

**Edit::** *Help* section of app suggests ways of installing windows using this app by creating bootable USB drives, which of course need access to another PC - not tried this

Comment: Is this still a good route to use even if I have no CD drive?

Comment: I managed to, yes. But I went to my parents house and used their computer to complete the process. Thank you very much!

Comment: this requires root, right?

Comment: @MarkYisri : yes.. added that to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

[ISO to USB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.iso2usb&hl=en_IN) app does the work same as rufus for windows

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZArchiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver) (Play Store link) to extract ISO to USB. In BIOS open EFI boot file present in USB (options like in HP: Run UEFI application). Once boot menu opens, install/recover Windows.