# How to add an image to the hard-disk of an android phone

Tags: boot

Dont mention about custom Roms, I want to load an image into the hard-disk and be able to access it from a computer can I do so?

I want to know how to write to memory, and that includes wipping off the / directory.

May be want to load linux into it(Assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) can help

> DriveDroid allows you to boot your PC from ISO/IMG files stored on your phone. This is ideal for trying Linux distributions or always having a rescue-system on the go... without the need to burn different CDs or USB pendrives.
>
> DriveDroid also includes a convenient download menu where you can download USB-images of a number of operating systems from your phone (like Mint, Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSUSE and Arch Linux). Around 35 different systems are available at this moment.

**Needs root**

Related [Creating a bootable USB through android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161036/131553)

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1

Comment: I want to wipe off  `/` contents, that means everything at the root directory and place something new there.

Comment: I don't understand that part- if you wipe off everything in root directory, it won't be a phone anymore and you can't use it. I am afraid I don't understand

Comment: I mean replacing it with some other contents and making it notable from there.

Comment: I still don't follow you - [are you talking of making your phone a bootable USB](http://www.geekomad.com/2013/08/how-to-make-android-phone-as-bootable.html)??? This app can do that as explained. If this still didn't help, please ask a separate question explaining your requirement clearly and linking this question as background if it helps